# NgRx selector filter null values

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Our web app loads values in the NgRx store which are set to null in the initial state. I'm looking for a way to nicely filter non-null values because I keep seeing in components

```
this.myValue = this.store.pipe(
  select(mySelector),
  filter(notNull),
);

// where 

const notNull = (data) => data !== null;
```

And I consider this code duplication, it'd be great to handle this at selector level. But I'm also open to other solutions.

One thing I tried is a custom `createSelector`:

```
import {createSelector, createSelectorFactory, defaultMemoize} from '@ngrx/store';

const isEqualOrNull = (a: any, b: any): boolean =>
  a === b || b === null;

const createSelectorNotNull = createSelectorFactory((projectionFn) =>
  defaultMemoize(projectionFn, isEqualOrNull));
```

Unfortunately, this solution would not handle initial `null` values, only further ones.

Is there a nice solution to this seemingly frequent problem?

Comment: can you share more code? why do you want to use createSelectorFactory ? you can have simple selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, I came to the same conclusion as @timdeschrver.

```
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { notNull } from './utils';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const selectNotNull = (selector, ...args) => (source$) =>
  select(selector, ...args)(source$)
    .pipe(filter(notNull));
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible, because as you already mentioned the first time it won't use the compare functions you provide and just executes and returns the result.

To avoid code duplication you could create [your own pipeable operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily).

Comment: The link is broken - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily . Would you update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
const isEqualOrNull = (state): boolean => state.a === state.b || state.b === null;



export const selectorNotNull = createSelector(
 youState,
 isEqualOrNull
);
```

You have to pass your state to the selector!